# Random database cursor size of 0

Tags: android, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have an issue with my app where sometimes the Arraylist shows on recyclerview, and sometimes it doesn't. Arraylist is populated from a DB SQLLite Cursor.

```
public List<OrderItem> getAllOrders(String vendor) {
    List<OrderItem> ordersList = new ArrayList<>();

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(
            LocalOrderQty.TABLE_NAME,
            new String[]{"*"},
            LocalOrderQty.COLUMN_VENDOR + " = ?",
            new String[]{vendor},
            null,
            null,
            null);

    Log.d(TAG, "Vendor name: " + vendor + " Cursor size " + cursor.getCount());

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do { //(String barcode, String imageURL, String name, Integer quantity, String unit, String vendor)
            ordersList.add(new OrderItem(
                    cursor.getString(1),
                    cursor.getString(4),
                    cursor.getString(2),
                    cursor.getInt(3),
                    cursor.getString(5),
                    cursor.getString(0)
            ));
            Log.d(TAG, "cursor1getstring: " + cursor.getString(1));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return ordersList;
}
```

This is my logcat:

```
D/DatabaseHelper: Vendor name: ABC Cursor size 5
D/DatabaseHelper: cursor1getstring: 9559001380099
cursor1getstring: 9559001380105
cursor1getstring: 9559001380792
cursor1getstring: 9559001380815
```

And then when it doesn't work, this is the logcat:

```
D/DatabaseHelper: Vendor name: ABC Cursor size 0
```

Even though when I open the database file from SQL Browser, there definitely is data and it's populated.

Is there something I need to improve on on my code?

This issue is random, sometimes the list shows up, sometimes it's 0.

Comment: did you try `db.query("select * from your_table where vendor='vendor_name'");` ?

Comment: Yup I did, it was the same

Comment: I think I just figured it out, but I have not find the solution yet. I think it's the time of my data being loaded into the local database, and trying to read it at about the same time, causing it to appear as 0 as the database connection is not closed yet.

The getAllOrder method was probably trying to read while it's not yet fully written.

Comment: But as you said that it happens Random, that shouldn't happen all the time right?

Comment: Have you checked orderlist size()?

Comment: Correct, it's random. Sometimes the data gets loaded "just in time" and sometimes it doesn't.

Comment: The data get loaded from the cloud to the local database.

Yes i've checked orderlist.size, sometimes it will appear as 0.

Comment: If the data gets loaded from the Cloud to the database then you must call the method after your db is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the data loaded from Firestore (asynchronously) sometimes do not finish in time before the database gets read again, therefore causing the size to be 0 as the method is trying to read while it's still being written.

A fix would be to wait for it to end first before reading it again.